How to replicate fitted value calculation from NLME model with cubic splines?
I'm fitting an nlme model using SITAR in R,
library(sitar)
#> Loading required package: nlme
ff <- na.omit(berkeley[berkeley$sex == 2 & berkeley$age >= 8 & berkeley$age <= 18, 
                       c('id', 'age', 'height')])
fh1 <- sitar(x = age, y = height, id = id, data = ff, df = 3, fixed = "a + b + c", random = "a")

Based on SITAR's paper, it says that the model specification is:

In my code, there are 3 fixed effects, $\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0$ and one random effect, $\alpha_i$. So the model I have is:
$$y_{it} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_i + h\left(\frac{age_{i}-\beta_0}{exp(-\gamma_0)}\right) + \epsilon_{it}$$
I want to make sure I'm understanding how to calculate the predicted values from SITAR. First, the predict.sitar gives me the following
Predicted values from model fit:
ages <- seq(0, 18, 0.1)
predicted_height <- predict(fh1, newdata = data.frame(age = ages),, type = "response", level = 0)
> head(predicted_height)
     301      301      301      301      301      301 
85.86228 86.40480 86.94732 87.48984 88.03236 88.57488 

Predicted values from hand calculation:
I want to use the model's coefficient estimates to replicate the predicted values above by 'hand calculating' them. Here are my model's estimated fixed effects:
> fixef(fh1)
         s1          s2          s3           a           b           c 
 35.1254398  55.2275889  32.2892681 124.2293895  -1.3156610   0.1576641 

I obtain the natural cubic spline fit based on Equation (1), i.e., calculating $h\left(\frac{age_{i}-\beta_0}{exp(-\gamma_0)}\right)$ and storing it in an object called basis.
basis <- ns((ages - fixef(fh1)[5])/exp(-fixef(fh1)[6]), df = 3)

Putting everything together:
predicted_height_hand_calculate <- fixef(fh1)[4] + fixef(fh1)[1] * basis[, 1] + fixef(fh1)[2] * basis[, 2] + fixef(fh1)[3] * basis[, 3]
> head(predicted_height_hand_calculate)
[1] 124.2294 124.5082 124.7871 125.0660 125.3449 125.6241

However, these do not match predicted_height from above. What's causing this discrepancy?

Not a complete answer, but too long for comments.
The SITAR model can be expressed as:
$$
y_{it} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_i + h\left(\frac{t - \beta_0}{e^{-\gamma_0}}\right) + \epsilon_{it}
$$
where:

$y_{it}$ is the measurement for subject $i$ at age $t$.
$\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0$ are fixed effects (size, tempo, and velocity).
$\alpha_i$ is a random intercept (individual deviation from $\alpha_0$).
$h(\cdot)$ is a cubic regression spline.
$\epsilon_{it}$ is the error term.

The fixed effects are represented by the coefficients $a, b, c$ in the SITAR model, corresponding to $\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0$. The random effect $\alpha_i$ accounts for individual variability.
The natural cubic spline is applied to the transformed age variable:
$$
\text{Transformed age} = \frac{\text{age} - \beta_0}{\exp(-\gamma_0)}
$$
The potential issues causing discrepancies include:

Transformation Consistency: Ensure that age transformation is correctly applied.
Cubic Spline Basis: Verify that the spline basis matches the internal calculation in the sitar package.
Fixed Effects Addition: Confirm the addition of $\alpha_0$ to spline components.

To manually calculate predicted values:

Transform Ages:

transformed_ages <- (ages - fixef(fh1)["b"]) / exp(-fixef(fh1)["c"])


Compute Spline Basis:

basis <- ns(transformed_ages, df = 3)


Calculate Predicted Values:

    predicted_height_hand_calculate <- fixef(fh1)["a"] + 
                                       fixef(fh1)["s1"] * basis[, 1] + 
                                       fixef(fh1)["s2"] * basis[, 2] + 
                                       fixef(fh1)["s3"] * basis[, 3]

The manual calculation should replicate the sitar package's results if all parameters and transformations are consistent. Checking internal functions within sitar may provide additional insights, especially concerning default settings or spline configurations.

You got the exact same thing that I did, which doesn't match the predicted_height from predict.sitar.

Just out of curiosity, did you use ChatGPT or some AI to generate your response? I thought your answer sounded a bit AI-generated so I tested it out myself, and I got a very similar response.
